# Возможность переобразования типов Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, типы

Есть функция, на вход которой всегда подается строка в виде '12x45x21'. Мне нужно пройтись по числам (разделенными "х") и проверить что это действительно числа. Как это лучше сделать?

```
def check_type(param):
    param = param.split('x')

    for i in param:
        try:
            return float(param)
        except:
            return False
```

Answer (score 6):

Вот так вот:

```
def check_type(param):
    param = param.split('x')

    for i in param:
        try:
            float(i)
        except:
            return False
    
    return True

print(check_type('12x45x21'))
```

Comment: Более красиво: `import re;lambda param: all(re.match('[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+', i) for i in param.split('x'))`.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157162/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2-python/1157169#1157169

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica воу, ну я бы не сказал, что это более красиво, если под "красиво" понимается читабельность, а не количество символов :)

Comment: Ну, я имел в виду "one-liner" ;)

Comment: Да и к тому же вроде нормально читается...

Answer (score 4):

```
import re

def check_type(param):
    return all(re.match('[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+', i) for i in param.split('x'))
```

Answer (score 1):

@andreymal:

> Если ожидаются только целые неотрицательные числа, то
>
> ```
> lambda param: all(x.isdigit() for x in param.split('x'))
> ```